# It is possible to create/install an iOS app like the macOS parental controls?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to create a app like macOS parental controls in iOS for giving permission for accessing certain apps on the device?

Comment: You could use [Lockdown](http://ioshacker.com/news/lockdown-pro-ios-7-becomes-available) if you're willing to jailbreak.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to at least some degree. Apps like [OurPact](http://ourpact.com) allow control of which apps your child is allowed to use.

Answer (score 0):

The sandboxing applied to all iOS apps does not allow this. You can enforce some restrictions via Settings->General->Restrictions but compared to Parental Control the options are rather limited.

Comment: thanks @patrix, i have to control the child from playing games so i can hide the other applications from our applications..